colab: name 'metadata' is not defined
Google Colab (в Synthetic Data Vault) не видит метаданные:
from sdv.single_table import CTGANSynthesizer

synthesizer = CTGANSynthesizer(metadata.csv)

synthesizer.fit(data.csv)

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-cd8dfb16b726> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 from sdv.single_table import CTGANSynthesizer
      2 
----> 3 synthesizer = CTGANSynthesizer(metadata.csv)
      4 
      5 synthesizer.fit(data.csv)

NameError: name 'metadata' is not defined

Файл metadata.csv. Перезагружал и с другими файлами и отдельно, не помогает.

Ну вы дальше то доки читайте. https://docs.sdv.dev/sdv/single-table-data/data-preparation/creating-metadata  Переменную metadata нужно ещё создать. Питон не знает, что это.

Да вот не совсем понятно про создание......

Используйте эту функцию для автоматического обнаружения метаданных из ваших данных, загруженных как объект pandas.DataFrame.
metadata = Metadata.detect_from_dataframe(
data=my_dataframe,
table_name='hotel_guests')            Получается, что my_dataframe необходимо из csv переформатировать в pandas.Dataframe?

Написал ответ. А так то Google Colab тут не при чём.

from sdv.single_table import CTGANSynthesizer

synthesizer = CTGANSynthesizer(metadata.csv)

Я так понимаю, "metadata.csv" - это файл с данными формата csv. Тогда нужно сделать следующее:

Прочитать файл "metadata.csv" в Pandas.DataFrame:

import pandas as pd
my_dataframe = pd.read_csv("metadata.csv")


Создать из датафрейма объект метаданных:

from sdv.metadata import Metadata

metadata = Metadata.detect_from_dataframe(
    data=my_dataframe,
    table_name='hotel_guests')


Наконец-то использовать эти метаданные:

from sdv.single_table import CTGANSynthesizer

synthesizer = CTGANSynthesizer(metadata)

Если я правильно понял документацию.
P.S. Что касается собственно ошибки.
----> 3 synthesizer = CTGANSynthesizer(metadata.csv)

NameError: name 'metadata' is not defined

С точки зрения Питона вы здесь как будто пытаетесь обращаться к полю csv переменной metadata, которая у вас в коде не описана. Поэтому такая ошибка.

Спасибо! Всё получилось!
